# ¿Como guardo una cookie con más de un campo?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Verán tengo este código:

```
alert("User_Name=" + document.getElementById("User_Name").value + ";" + 
              "Password=" + document.getElementById("Password").value+ ";" + 
              "Name_Surname=" + document.getElementById("Name_Surname").value + ";" + 
              "Birthday=" + document.getElementById("birthday").value + ";" + 
              "Direccion=" + document.getElementById("Direccion").value + ";" + 
              "email=" + document.getElementById("email").value + ";" + 
              "payment=" + valor_radios + ";" + 
              "NCuenta=" + document.getElementById("Ncard").value + ";" + 
              "mes=" + document.getElementById("mes").value + ";" + 
              "ano=" + document.getElementById("ano").value + ";"+ 
              "codigo=" + document.getElementById("codigo").value + ";" + 
              "Lenguaje=" + document.getElementById("lenguaje").value + ";" );

document.cookie="User_Name=" + document.getElementById("User_Name").value + ";" + 
              "Password=" + document.getElementById("Password").value+ ";" + 
              "Name_Surname=" + document.getElementById("Name_Surname").value + ";" + 
              "Birthday=" + document.getElementById("birthday").value + ";" + 
              "Direccion=" + document.getElementById("Direccion").value + ";" + 
              "email=" + document.getElementById("email").value + ";" + 
              "payment=" + valor_radios + ";" + 
              "NCuenta=" + document.getElementById("Ncard").value + ";" + 
              "mes=" + document.getElementById("mes").value + ";" + 
              "ano=" + document.getElementById("ano").value + ";"+ 
              "codigo=" + document.getElementById("codigo").value + ";" + 
              "Lenguaje=" + document.getElementById("lenguaje").value + ";";
```

El caso es que se que coge todos los campos correctamente, ya que imprimo una alerta para verlos. Sin embargo solo se guarda el primer valor "UserName" los demás no se guardan, cuando más a delante escribo en el código:

```
var cookie = document.cookie;
```

Y miro su valor con el debugger me sale solo "UserName=nombre", sin embargo del resto nada, y por lo tanto, al intentar recuperar los otros campos, no me encuentra otra cosa que no sea el nombre de usuario.

¿Que tengo mal?

Comment: Asumo que ya sabes que es lo que estaba mal dado al tiempo que ha pasado pero, porqué simplemente no las guardaste en un objeto? no era mas facil? y si las querias en string usabas JSON.sringify() .-.

Answer (score 0):

Este sería una manera de guardar más de un dato en una cookie:

```js
    document.cookie =
        'galleta=' + encodeURIComponent('chocolate') +
        '; max-age=' + 60*60*24*30 +
        '; path=/; domain=tudominio.com' ;
```

No sé porqué no te funciona, que yo haya visto no has hecho nada mal. Podría ser problema de tu navegador. Yo probaría a hacer cada cookie por separado o cómo te he puesto.

Answer (score 0):

JSON puede codificar estos campos como una cadena tipo var arr = {User_Name: 'nombre', Password: 'pass123'}" los colocas en la cookie, recupera cuando es necesario y decodifica de nuevo en una matriz / objeto JavaScript.
Por ejemplo:

```js
var userName = $("#User_Name").text();
var pass = $("#Password").text();

arr = { 
userName : userName,
pass : pass
}
//Codificando objeto como una cadena
var json_str = JSON.stringify(arr);

document.cookie = 'nombreCookie = '+json_str+';';

//Recuperando el contenido de la cookie como un objeto
var json_str2 = getCookie('nombreCookie');
var arr_new = JSON.parse(json_str2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="User_Name">name</div>
<div id="Password">pass123</div>
```

**Nota:** La función getCookie() usada en el ejemplo no es nativa, creo que ya lo sabes pero cabe la aclaración.

Comment: Buena por sugerir json pero hay varias cosas que estas omitiendo como que en js moderno no es necesario crear un key:value si la key se llama igual a la variable ya declarada, en este caso podría ser `var foo = true; let obj = {foo}`, segundo, en JS es mala practica declarar variables capitalizadas para datos que no sean constructores, a su vez es mejor usar camelCase en lugar de underscore para separar palabras  (como tus primeras dos variables) y por su puesto JQuery hasta cuando.... pero buena igual recuerda siempre mantenerse informado para fomentar las buenas practicas, un saludo

Comment: @DєηyηCrawford gracias por la critica constructiva. En mi defensa digo que el objeto fué creado mediante el modelo key:value para que el autor pueda acceder rápidamente a la propiedad del objeto, porque veo que en este caso tiene muchas. Gracias por aclararme la nomenclatura correcta para declarar variables, no le presté atención a ello. Lo de la librería JQuery si te lo refuto, cada quién con sus gustos. Saludos !!